# Running Java makefile on Windows

Tags: java, makefile

I know makefiles are totally outdated for Java projects but we have to make one for a course assignment. Here is the makefile they gave us to use:

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: $(classes)

clean :
    rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
    $(JAVAC) $<
```

I assume this should work because my prof gave it to us, does this look correct? Common practices/clarity isn't required it just needs to compile the one `.java` file in the same folder.

Assuming the file is okay, how do I run it from windows cmd prompt?

Comment: Wow, you need to get a new teacher.  If you are working in a Java ecosystem, you should be using ant or maven.

Comment: I looked at that question and the answer is in reference to Visual Studio, plus the the entire question is about a C/C++ makefile.